# Keyboard move up and down with many subviews with uiTextfield

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I need to move a keyboard up and down. I have many subviews with many uiTextfields. These subviews has one superview and this superview is in the scroll view.

I can't move up a view using below code:

```
- (void) keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)notification{
    NSDictionary *info = [notification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey]CGRectValue].size;
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0);
    self.Scroll_view.contentInset = contentInsets;
    self.Scroll_view.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}

- (void) keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification *)notification{
   UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
   self.Scroll_view.contentInset = contentInsets;
   self.Scroll_view.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}
```

This code working fine when i place all the UITextfields in the ScrollView(Not into the subviews), But i need to do with subview and also move keyboard up and down.
How can i move a keyboard up and down while press keyboard Next/Return key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
- (void)animateViewUpToTargetYOrigin:(CGFloat)yValue
{

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification object:nil queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
        CGFloat yOrigin = 0;
        CGFloat keyboardYOrigin = [[[note userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].origin.y;
        if (yValue > keyboardYOrigin) {
            yOrigin = yValue - keyboardYOrigin;
        }
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{

                self.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, -yOrigin, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);


        }];


}];
```

Using this code you only need to call this method in textfield didbeginediting, and pass the yOrigin(textfield)+height(textField) as y value in it.
If you textFields are in Scrollview or any sub view convert their frame values in respect to self.view before sending Y value.

E.g:

```
CGRect textFieldRectWithRespectToSelfView = [textField.superview convertRect:textField.frame toView:self.view];
[self.view animateViewUpToTargetYOrigin: textFieldRectWithRespectToSelfView.orgin.y + textFieldRectWithRespectToSelfView.size.height];
```

When you call `[textField resignFirstResponder]`, `self.view` comes back to its original position. This happens because the `UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification` always keeps listening to keyboard frame changes.

I do have a demo project in github as an example please refer to it:

https://github.com/subhajitregor/ViewMoveUpExample

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Welcome, my pleasure

Comment: UITextfield in the subview2 y position is some 234 but the UITextfield in the subview3 y position is 150. Kindly help me, if you know why its showing wrong position? why Its take lower position?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, can you please give a screenshot of your viewstack, or a demo project with that only viewcontroller, then I may be able to help you better.

Comment: I have edited the answer and added a link and also changed on how to get the rect. I think you have that problem as when converting the rect you are not providing the `textField.superview`, as I did not have included previously, I have edited that part also, please check and do reply I it solves your problem

Comment: Thank you so much. Its working fine. Really github project was helpful. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

In `viewDidLoad` method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                              selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                                  name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                                object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                              selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
                                                  name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                                object:nil];
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
     // the keyboard is hiding reset the table's height
     NSTimeInterval animationDuration =
     [[[aNotification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
     CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
     frame.origin.y += 150;
     [UIView beginAnimations:@"ResizeForKeyboard" context:nil];
     [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
     self.view.frame = frame;
     [UIView commitAnimations];
 }

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)aNotification

{
     // the keyboard is showing so resize the table's height
     NSTimeInterval animationDuration =
     [[[aNotification userInfo]     objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
     CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
     frame.origin.y -= 150;
     [UIView beginAnimations:@"ResizeForKeyboard" context:nil];
     [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
     self.view.frame = frame;
     [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply.